# creating many dataframes as subsets of one large one

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code which extracts  subsets of a dataframe to individual dataframes which represent rainfall events:

```
j=list(range(len(eventdf)))
for k in range(len(eventdf)):
    
    dfname= 'event'+str(j[k])
    dfnatp=meandf2.iloc[eventdf.iloc[k,0]: eventdf.iloc[k,1]+2]
    dfnatp.to_csv(dfname+'.csv', sep=',')
```

while I can very easily dump each dataframe to a .csv file, to do anything with it means that I then have to read it back in.
how do I create each dataframe with name given by the value of 'dfname' in the same way that I can name each csv file?

Comment: IIUC, you can try using `dict` of dataframes with `dict keys` as "name given by the value of dfname"

Comment: @MuhammadHassan how do I do that when the number of dataframes required will change each time I run a different time period. (if it helps, the number of required dataframes will equal  the number of values in 'j'). I'm not a python expert, I'm a climate researcher!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate Muhammad's suggestion a little more, you can create an empty dictionary like this (before your `for` loop):

```
dfdict = {}
```

Then you can create new dictionary entries like this (inside your `for` loop):

```
dfdict[dfname] = dfnatp
```

These entries will have `dfname` as the key and `dfnatp` as the value, so you can access each `dfnatp` by using `dfdict['eventXXX']`, where eventXXX is your identifier.

[Here is an introduction to python's dictionary data structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary/) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, consider a dictionary of data frames which you can achieve with dictionary comprehension. You lose no functionality of a data frame if saved in a dict or list. Since you need to also save to CSV, consider a defined method. Below uses F-strings for string interpolation.

```py
def proc_data(k):
    dfnatp = meandf2.iloc[eventdf.iloc[k,0]: eventdf.iloc[k,1]+2]
    dfnatp.to_csv(f"event_{k}.csv")
    return dfnatp

df_dict = {
    f"event_{k}": proc_data(k) for k in range(len(eventdf))
}

# ACCESS INDIVIDUAL DATA FRAMES
df_dict["event_0"]
df_dict["event_1"]
df_dict["event_2"]
...
```